# I have done something wrong

Tags: errors

I have done something wrong and get \end{document} error
Any advice would be appreciated.  The presentation had printed a few times but when i get it just right i get that message.

Comment: Welcome to TeX. You'll get a better response if you can post your `.tex` file so we can identify the error.

Comment: Also, please provide the exact text of the error.

Comment: @Hugh I'm sorry but this is *not* good advice. Posting an entire file is exactly not the way to solve a problem on the site.  While more information is certainly needed, Wayne really needs to debug the problem by moving the end document progressively back in his own document until he finds the error. The most likely cause given the vague information here is that he has forgotten an `\end{...}`of some environment.

Comment: You're right. Sorry -- too hasty.

Comment: The error is l. 102 \end{document}

Comment: When I click on go to error it goes to line 102 and highlights \end{document}

Comment: Error detection w.r.t. line number is notoriously difficult in TeX. You need to look at the console output or the log file, and look at the *first* error reported. TeX will try to go on as long as it can and can produce a whole string of irrelevant errors.

Comment: I have found a few errors but still get that same error message

Comment: @WayneCharters: Can you post your code? Edit your question and include it there, or add it to [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: Love the title to this one! Hard to give good advice, however....

Comment: @jon May I give him a +1 for the title and the "old newbie"?

Comment: @CarLaTeX -- haha. I thought the same thing!

Comment: @jon OK, +1 approved, solidarity because I am an old newbie too!

Comment: Wayne, in case you have modified something recently, try to comment that code to try to localize the error...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help and advice.  The problem was that I had my { and } the wrong way around throughout the whole document.  A beginners error for sure and you may all have a laugh at my expense.  If I had not been told to go back through the logs I would still be here looking blankly at the unresponsive screen.
Cheers,
Wayne